# How to gain access to Box2d's b2CollideCircles in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, box2d, objective-c++, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to test out some collision detection with Box2d (using [this method](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2692)). I've added the source and headers to my XCode project, and have added a recursive `./**` to my header search paths. It appears to build fine.

Unfortunately, I can't use the collision detection methods directly, for reasons I don't understand.

`CollisionTest.h:`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CollisionTest : NSObject
-(void)test;
@end
```

`CollisionTest.mm:` *(renamed to mm properly for access to C++ code)*

```
#import "CollisionTest.h"
#import "Box2D.h"

@implementation CollisionTest

-(void)test {
  b2CircleShape *circle1 = new b2CircleShape();
  circle1->m_radius = 5.0;
  b2Vec2 circle1Pos(0.0, 0.0);
  b2Transform *transform1 = new b2Transform();
  transform1->Set(circle1Pos, 0.0);
  ... ditto for circle2 ...

  b2Manifold *manifold = new b2Manifold();
  b2CollideCircles(&manifold, circle1, transform1, circle2, transform2);
  if (manifold->pointCount > 0){
    NSLog(@"collided");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"no collision");
  }
}

@end
```

The circle setup code runs fine, but the compiler craps out on the `b2CollideCircles` line with "No matching function for call to 'b2CollideCircles'".

`Box2d.h` does not seem to include `b2Collision.h` by default, so I've tried adding it to my implementation file both as `#import "b2Collision.h"` as well as `#import <Box2d/Collision/b2Collision.h>`, but the error remains the same.

How do I access the collision methods directly?

Answer (score 1):

The error message was that the compiler couldn't find a method that fit the signature I was using—the variables I was passing did not fit the types of the declared method parameters, and since C++ allows method overloading it did not register as the same method.

Properly defining the variables (C++ is not Objective-C) and carefully reading the method signature produces code that works fine:

```
b2CircleShape circle1;
circle1.m_radius = 5.0;
b2Vec2 circle1Pos(10.01, 0.0);
b2Transform transform1;
transform1.Set(circle1Pos, 0.0);
...
b2Manifold manifold;
b2CollideCircles(&manifold, &circle1, transform1, &circle2, transform2);
```